# Matching any character in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a state machine which is capable of matching the comments. So it can handle :

```
/* /* */ */
```

But I bogged down of skipping the contents that are inside the comment lines. Currently my `comments-word` regex looks something strange :

```
[0-9A-Za-zA-Z0-9\*\(\*\*\)\.\{\}\_\;\,\-\:" "\@]*
```

Are there any simple regex ( in java ) which matches all the characters? Alphabets along with special characters?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Had you taken help from `Google`, you would have got the answer in the first link only. Metacharacter dot(.) matches any character except newline..

Comment: Are you sure you want be able to parse comments in comments?

Comment: How fortunate OP is. There is no exact duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 1):

use `.` (dot) if you want to match any character.

[See here: **Dot**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

Comment: Do quote that -  except newline

Answer (score 1):

`.` matches anything once.  `.*` will match 0 or more of anything, while `.+` will match one or more, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

`.` is the character that matches all other characters, with the possible exception of newlines (depending on whether [`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) is enabled).

If you want to match everything EXCEPT a certain character or two, use `[^...]` syntax (such as `[^0-9a-fA-F]` to avoid matching every hexadecimal digit).

It is often useful to add a trailing `?` to expressions with a dot, to match the fewest characters as possible (such as `.*?` or `.+?`). Otherwise, an unterminated dot expression may match the rest of the string.